# kCGBlendModeClear doesn't clear, why?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm writing some lines of code to get acquainted with the basics of Quartz 2d.
I am trying to draw and image an then clear it through the kCGBlendModeClear blend mode. Here's the code of my `UIView` subclass code, whose background color is set to orange through IB:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *brush = [UIImage imageNamed:@"brush.png"] ;
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx,kCGBlendModeNormal ); 
    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(100, 100, 26, 25), [brush CGImage]);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctx, kCGBlendModeClear);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);

    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(ctx, CGRectMake(110, 110, 5, 5)); // HERE!
}
```

Reading the docs and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629409/how-to-draw-a-transparent-stroke-or-anyway-clear-part-of-an-image-on-the-iphone) I thought that line marked HERE would produce a hole in the image I had previously drawn. Instead it creates a black circle on it (should be orange).

To debug, I tried adding my custom view over an orange uiview. This time my custom view has a black background. The hole  of line HERE is correct, but I wonder why the black color of the view. Even more strangely, if I do myView.backgroundColor I can set a background color (shouldn't this be overridden by my drawRect implementation?).

I am clearly missing some basics of Quartz, can anyone help?

Davide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things.

First, the Porter-Duff blend modes are only guaranteed to work in bitmap-based contexts. (i.e., contexts created by `CGBitmapContextCreate`)

Second, `kCGBlendModeClear` is defined as `R = 0` — it doesn't even check src or dst pixels. So even though it's not guaranteed to work here, it appears that it is working correctly.

(see `CGContext.h` for better explanation than the docs give.)

Comment: two subquestion: 1) do you see kCGBlendModeClea as a viable way to implement a rubber tool? 2) Could you tell me something more about R?

Comment: 1) No. `R=0` is pretty useless, you can't even set the clear color. 2) Blend modes can be expressed in terms of R, S, and D, where S is the source pixel, D is the destination pixel and R is the resulting pixel. This gives you a handy shorthand for describing blend modes, e.g, `R = S + D*(1 - Sa)` for source-over (`kCGBlendModeNormal`) It's pretty well explained in the comments beginning at CGContext.h:84

Comment: Thanks! I had guessed ModeCLear wasn't the answer, but it's nice to have confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

For `kCGBlendModeClear` to work the view must not be opaque and must not have a background color set.

In addition, the following line is unnecessary, because `kCGBlendModeClear` does not care about the fill color:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
```