# transparency on uiimageview should show image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to draw a transparent stroke (or anyway clear part of an image) on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629409/how-to-draw-a-transparent-stroke-or-anyway-clear-part-of-an-image-on-the-iphon)

I have a uiimage view on that a transparent layer is there
if we make touch on that transparent layer that touched part transparent layer should be erased and should show the image back of it.. how can i do this....?
thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: UIImage    * backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
    CALayer*    aLayer = [CALayer layer];
    CGFloat nativeWidth = CGImageGetWidth(backgroundImage.CGImage);
    CGFloat nativeHeight = CGImageGetHeight(backgroundImage.CGImage);
    CGRect      startFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, nativeWidth, nativeHeight);
    aLayer.contents = (id)backgroundImage.CGImage;
    aLayer.frame = startFrame;
     [self.view.layer addSublayer:aLayer];
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 ;

Comment: @pammu do u want to erase the bit of selected  image from the source image?

Comment: i have a image on that  an overlay image is there when i erse the overlay it should show yha part of the image

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding you want to erase the part of the image by touching...
Is that right ?

Try this code for erasing by touches moved part of image....

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:canvasView];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    currentTouch = [touch locationInView:canvasView];

    CGFloat brushSize = 35;
    CGColorRef strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scratchView.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [canvasView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, canvasView.frame.size.width, canvasView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, brushSize);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, strokeColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lastTouch.x, lastTouch.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, currentTouch.x, currentTouch.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    canvasView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastTouch = [touch locationInView:canvasView];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

I hope this will help you....