# How to change UIImageView alpha onTouchMoved

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am making a project on touch moved I want to change the alpha or visibility (whatever possible) of the image at the point where it is touched. Lets say Unhidethat particular point of image..

**PS I already know how to erase the image. I am looking for unerase**

Comment: Hope this solution in apple communities will help you [https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1933811?start=0&tstart=0](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1933811?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: Did u get solution for this issue?

Comment: Yeah I got it I was planning to resolve it either way changing alpha or unerase But you saved me....
I don't think so I get any relevant and till day wch can help so I am gonna do that in the prev way you told me

Comment: Enjoy keep posting queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this project does exactly what you're looking for : https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STScratchView

You have 2 images where one is the hidden image and the other one is the one that you scratch off.

Or even this project : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/scratch-n-see

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for not having a good format for the code, for they are copied from my blog.
It takes me a lot to edit.

## 1 To hide the part that you touch on.

When your finger moves, erase some parts :

```
- (UIImage *)erasePartsMoved {
UIImage *image = nil;
UIColor *color = [UIColor whiteColor];
CGFloat width = 5.0f;
CGSize imageContextSize = self.imageView.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageContextSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, width);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [color CGColor]);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.touchStartPoint.x, self.touchStartPoint.y);
//Do something needed.
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.touchEndPoint.x, self.touchEndPoint.y);

CGContextStrokePath(context);

image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;}
```

## 2 Your image is not visible at first, for example, transparent.

Get the point touched, then calculate a circle with the touched point, and finally change the alpha of the pixels in the circle:

```
typedef struct _singleRGBA{
unsigned char red;
unsigned char green;
unsigned char blue;
unsigned char alpha;} RGBA;
```

To change the pixel's alpha :

```
void filterOpacity(UInt8 *pixelBuf, UInt32 offset, void *context){
double val = *((double*)context);
int a = offset+3;
int alpha = pixelBuf[a];
pixelBuf[a] = SAFECOLOR(alpha * val);}
```

I hope the above would do a favor.
Funny question, I would like to do a runnable demo later.

Answer (score 0):

I believe alpha is the property of the entire view so all you can do is draw on that particular point...  refer this may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629409/how-to-draw-a-transparent-stroke-or-anyway-clear-part-of-an-image-on-the-iphon) is what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Ankit But I want to unhide from hide

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    //load super view
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //to decrease alpha. 
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiperight=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer  alloc]     
     initWithTarget:self action: @selector(setalpha_decrease:)];
    [swiperight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperight];

    //to increase alpha.     
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer  alloc] 
    initWithTarget:self action: @selector(setalpha_increase:)];
    [swipeleft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];



  }


  -(void) setalpha_decrease:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {

    imgview.alpha= imgtomove.alpha-(imgtomove.alpha/10);
  }



  -(void) setalpha_increase:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) gestureRecognizer {

    imgview.alpha= imgtomove.alpha+(imgtomove.alpha/10);

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put an empty view on top which is filled with a colour or texture and then using @AnkitSrivastava answer let the touch rub away parts of the view's background, revealing the hidden image behind.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *t = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    float alpha = [t locationInView:self.view].x / self.view.frame.size.width;
    _img.alpha = alpha;
}
```